# Generate T4MVC url inside ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Is there a way to generate a Url that is not part of an ApiController inside a ApiController using T4MVC?  I dont have an option to do so.  `controller.Url` is null when I run the code below.

```
var controller = new UrlController();

                foreach (var e in @event.Event.Reports)
                {
                    e.Url = controller.Url.Action(EventReportTypes.GetTypes(e.ReportType, @event.Event.Id, AssetOutput.Html, false));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this.

```
 var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
                if (url != null)
                {
                    e.Url = url.ActionAbsolute(EventReportTypes.GetTypes(e.ReportType, @event.Id, AssetOutput.Html, false)).Split('&')[0];
                }
```